# Java - error: constructor "constructor name" in class "class name" cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

Before asking my question I want to make some things clear.  First, I am new to Java and programming in general.  Second, This is my first post so please go easy on me if I did something wrong.  Finally, I **DO NOT** want any specific solutions to my assignment in any responses to this post.  Those issues are for me to figure out.  What I do want is an explanation as to why my test code wont compile/run.  To better understand the issue I will paste the assignment information, then the Driver class that is given, then my class code that is accessed by the Driver class.  The compiler error I have is shown in the title, but since it is fairly vague, [**here**](http://prntscr.com/7srf2j) is a screenshot of the exact errors I'm getting.

**The following is the assignment:**

You are to design a class “LostPuppy.java” which represents a puppy lost in a multi-floor building that
contains the same number of rooms on each floor. During instantiation (or creation) of an object of this class,
each room on each floor will be initialized as empty (you will actually use the space ‘ ‘ character for this
purpose) and a random room will be chosen where the puppy is lost. For this purpose, the character “P” will
be placed in this random location. Further details on the constructor is listed below.

An object of this class is used as a game for two players to take turns searching for the puppy, one room at a
time until the unfortunate little canine is found. The instantiation of this object and the search will be performed
by a “driver” program which has been provided to you allowing you to only have to concentrate on developing
the class (the driver program is in the file “PuppyPlay.java”)

**Fields (of course, all fields are private):**

- A character (char) array named myHidingPlaces. This represents the building where the rows are floors
  and the columns are rooms on each floor (this building has an unusual numbering system; the floors and
  rooms both start at zero).
- Two integers that will hold the floor and room where the puppy is lost, named myFloorLocation and
  myRoomLocation.
- A char named myWinner which will be assigned the player’s character when a player finds the puppy
  (the driver program uses digits ‘1’ and ‘2’ to more clearly distinguish the players from the puppy).
- A boolean named myFound which is set to true when the puppy is found.

**Constructor:**

- Receives two integer parameters as the user’s input for the number of floors and rooms of the building
  in which the puppy is lost.
- The constructor instantiates the 2D array “myHidingPlaces” as a character array with the first parameter
  for the rows (theFloors) and the second parameter as the columns (theRooms).
- Initialize myHidingPlaces’ cells, each to contain a space ‘ ‘ (done with single quotes)
- Set myFloorLocation (floor puppy is on) randomly based using the first parameter
- Set myRoomLocation (room puppy is in) randomly based using the second parameter
- Set myHidingPlaces[myFloorLocation][myRoomLocation] to the char ‘P’
- Set myWinner to a single space
- Set myFound to false

**Methods:**

- roomSearchedAlready receives the floor and room to be searched and returns true if the room has
  already been searched, false otherwise.
- puppyLocation receives the floor and room to be searched and returns true if the floor and room are
  where the puppy is lost, false otherwise. This method should NOT change any of the fields.
- indicesOK receives the floor and room to be searched and returns true if the floor and room values are
  within the array indices range, false otherwise (used to check that these indices will not cause an error
  when applied to the array).
- numberOfFloors returns how many floors are in the building (the first floor starts at zero).
- numberOfRooms returns how many rooms are on each floor of the building (the first room starts at
  zero and all floors have the same number of rooms).
- searchRoom receives the floor and room to be searched and also the current player (as a char type)
  and returns true if the puppy is found, false otherwise. If the puppy is NOT found searchRoom also
  sets the myHidingPlaces array at the received floor and room location to the received player value (a ‘1’
  or a ‘2’) OR, when found, sets the myWinner field to the current player AND sets myFound to true.
- toString displays the current hidingPlaces array and it’s contents EXCEPT the location of the puppy
  which remains hidden until he/she is found at which point toString will be called (by the driver) and both
  the player who found the puppy and a ‘P’ will be displayed in the same cell….
- NOW, and perhaps the awkward portion of the toString output. Normally, when displaying a 2D array,
  the [0][0] cell is displayed in the upper left corner as with matrices. However, because the puppy
  decided to get lost in a building and not a matrix, it would make more visual sense to have the first floor
  (row 0) displayed on the bottom, second floor above it… and finally the top floor, well… on top! To
  save words, look closely at the sample run provided on the next page. Your output should look the
  same as what is seen on the next page in the sample run.

**Here is the Driver program:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This program is used as a driver program to play the game from the
 * class LostPuppy.  Not to be used for grading!
 *
 * A puppy is lost in a multi-floor building represented in the class 
 * LostPuppy.class.  Two players will take turns searching the building
 * by selecting a floor and a room where the puppy might be.
 *
 * @author David Schuessler
 * @version Spring 2015
 */

public class PuppyPlay
{
  /**
   * Driver program to play LostPuppy.
   *
   * @param theArgs may contain file names in an array of type String
   */
  public static void main(String[] theArgs)
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    LostPuppy game; 
    int totalFloors;
    int totalRooms;
    int floor;
    int room;
    char[] players = {'1', '2'};
    int playerIndex;
    boolean found = false;
    Random rand = new Random();

    do 
    {
      System.out.print("To find the puppy, we need to know:\n"
                       + "\tHow many floors are in the building\n"
                       + "\tHow many rooms are on the floors\n\n"
                       + "             Please enter the number of floors: ");
      totalFloors = s.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Please enter the number of rooms on the floors: ");
      totalRooms = s.nextInt();
      s.nextLine();    // Consume previous newline character    

      // Start the game: Create a LostPuppy object:
      game = new LostPuppy(totalFloors, totalRooms);

      // Pick starting player
      playerIndex = rand.nextInt(2);

      System.out.println("\nFloor and room numbers start at zero '0'");

      do 
      {

        do 
        {
          System.out.println("\nPlayer " + players[playerIndex]
                             + ", enter floor and room to search separated by a space: ");
          floor = s.nextInt();
          room = s.nextInt();

          //for testing, use random generation of floor and room
          //floor = rand.nextInt(totalFloors);
          //room = rand.nextInt(totalRooms);
        } while (!game.indicesOK(floor, room) 
                 || game.roomSearchedAlready(floor, room));


        found = game.searchRoom(floor, room, players[playerIndex]);
        playerIndex = (playerIndex + 1) % 2;
        System.out.println("\n[" + floor + "], [" + room + "]");
        System.out.println(game.toString());
        s.nextLine();
      } while (!found);

      playerIndex = (playerIndex + 1) % 2;
      System.out.println("Great job player " + players[playerIndex] +"!");
      System.out.println("Would you like to find another puppy [Y/N]? ");
    } 
    while (s.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
  }
}
```

**Finally, here is my test code:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LostPuppy
{

   char[][] myHidingPlaces;
   int myFloorLocation;
   int myRoomLocation;
   char myWinner;
   boolean myFound;
   Random random = new Random();

   public void LostPuppy(int theFloors, int theRooms)
   {// this ^ void is the issue and is now removed from my code(answered 7/14/2015 on stack overflow)
      char[][] myHidingPlaces = new char[theFloors][theRooms];

      for (int i = 0; i < theFloors; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < theRooms; j++)
         {
            myHidingPlaces[i][j] = ' ';
         }
      }

      myFloorLocation = random.nextInt(theFloors);
      myRoomLocation = random.nextInt(theRooms);
      myHidingPlaces[myFloorLocation][myRoomLocation] = 'P';
      myWinner = ' ';
      myFound = false;  
   }
   public boolean roomSearchedAlready(int floor, int room)
   {
      if (myHidingPlaces[floor][room] == '1' || 
          myHidingPlaces[floor][room] == '2')
          {
            return true;
          }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public boolean puppyLocation(int floor, int room)
   {
      if (myHidingPlaces[floor][room] == 'P')
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public boolean indicesOK(int floor, int room)
   {
      if (floor <= myHidingPlaces.length || room <= myHidingPlaces[0].length)
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public int numberOfFloors()
   {
      return myHidingPlaces.length - 1;
   }
   public int numberOfRooms()
   {
      return myHidingPlaces[0].length - 1;
   }

   public boolean searchRoom(int floor, int room, char player)
   {
      if (myFound = true)
      {
         myWinner = player;
         myFound = true;
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         myHidingPlaces[floor][room] = player;
         return false;
      }
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return "this is a test";

   }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to have this line "`public void building(int theFloors, int theRooms)`" be your constructor for the `LostPuppy` class? (good effort on the question, BTW.)

Comment: How do you expect `new LostPuppy(totalFloors, totalRooms)` to work when you haven't defined any constructors for `LostPuppy`? Read the error messages that you have (hint: they are not vague and, in fact, are perfectly unambiguous) and realize that it basically says that you are trying to call methods that don't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I DO NOT want any specific solutions to my assignment in any responses
>   to this post. Those issues are for me to figure out. What I do want is
>   an explanation as to why my test code wont compile/run.

This line

```
game = new LostPuppy(totalFloors, totalRooms);
```

Won't compile because you haven't defined any constructor that expect two `int` as arguments (totalFloors and totalRooms).

In order to fix this, declare in your class `LostPuppy` a constructor such as

```
public LostPuppy(int totalFloors, int totalRooms)
{
    //Do something here with paremeters..
}
```

---

This line

```
while (!game.indicesOK(floor, room)
```

Won't compile because you haven't defined any `indicesOk` method in your `LostPuppy` class.

Create a method such as

```
public boolean indicesOK(int floot, int room)
{
    //return some conditions
}
```

Comment: @Jean-François Savard had a quick question tho, after adding this method: http://prntscr.com/7srv8m  

I get this error:  http://prntscr.com/7srvdy

I don't see how it could be null in this case.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard so even though I have char[][] myHidingPlaces; earlier in my code, it won't recognize myHidingPlaces as initialized?  It has to be initialized in the method it's used in?  Or is it because I changed the array in a previous method, but outside that method the field is still null?

Comment: @Jean-François Savard right, what i meant to say was that I assigned values to the 2D array in my constructor here: http://prntscr.com/7ss0j8.  I thought that the array lengths would stay and I could use them from another method.  So you're saying I have to find a way to get the length values without using myHidingPlaces?  Or is there another way to do that?

Comment: @Jean-François Savard I updated my code, adding the indicesOK method.  The driver program will never change so I left that the same.

Comment: @Trafton the problem is because in your method you re-create a variable `myHidingPlaces` which hide the other variable thus you never assign to the class-scoped array. Change `char[][] myHidingPlaces = ...` to `myHidingPlaces = ..`

Comment: @Jean-François Savard I removed the "char[][]" from "myHidingPlaces = new char[theFloors][theRooms];", but I'm still getting this error: http://prntscr.com/7ss7nl

Answer (score 2):

I think your `building` method should be constructor:

```
public LostPuppy(int theFloors, int theRooms)
{
  myHidingPlaces = new char[theFloors][theRooms]; //this line

  for (int i = 0; i < theFloors; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < theRooms; j++)
     {
        myHidingPlaces[i][j] = ' ';
     }
  }

  myFloorLocation = random.nextInt(theFloors);
  myRoomLocation = random.nextInt(theRooms);
  myHidingPlaces[myFloorLocation][myRoomLocation] = 'P';
  myWinner = ' ';
  myFound = false;  
}
```

Note: look at the marked line, do not define type, if you define type, it becomes local variable instead of instance variable.